# Add Kubernetes resource to Environment hosted in Azure subscription with different AAD tenant

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We run our Azure pipelines with AAD tenant @microsoft.com.
We want to deploy/control our deployments via AzurePipelines/Environment, and add an AKS resource from Azure subscription (that is hosted with @pme.gbl AAD tenant).

Kubernetes resources being listed on the VSO UI / Environment/ Kubernetes, are all related to @microsoft.com AAD tenant.

How do we add AKS resources for @pme.gbl AAD tenant and related Azure subscriptions ?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use service account for that ? Because service account way gives you the least privilege ability which is excellent for better security. You can control service account abilities with role bindings in Kubernetes granularly. Because Azure Kubernetes Provider  (other than service account) granted tha access scope same with you have into environments, with that way everyone can use your access scope in target environments –

Comment: didn't quite understand. Use service account of [at]pme.gbl tenant to interact with [at]microsoft azure pipelines ... is that possible?

Comment: service accounts are independent from Azure tenants.